# pytest-selenium use mobile_emulation or add userAgent in setting

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

In the Selenium we could use mobileEmulation to change chrome driver to mobile mode

```
mobile_emulation = {
        "deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19" }
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
    webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)
```

I have check the pytest-selenium have capabilities options but not working for user agents

is there any solution for me to simulate mobile in pytest-selenium?

thanks

Comment: That looks like the code from the [example](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation). What do you mean by "not working"? What happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: Oh i want to use the pytest-selenium report , so i'd to pass the useragent to it , seems not working , the chrome browser not effect for the useragent and metrics

Comment: I'm afraid that's still not clear to me. Can you show exactly what you currently see, and what you would expect to see instead if it were working?

Answer (score 0):

Temp solution is place the code on the conftest.py

using the yield diver to let the pytest-selenium to get the dirver info.

```
@pytest.yield_fixture
def mobileSelenium(request):
    mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19" }


    chrome_options = Options() 
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation) 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)
    request.node._driver = driver
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```